# Are there implicit constraints for resource groups in a pacemaker cluster?

Tags: rhel, cluster, pacemaker

According to redhat's official documentation, all resources in a resource group implicitly have colocation and order constraints. But from the tests i did in my lab setup i can't see any constraints and resources in the same resource groups are started on different nodes.

```
[root@node1 conf]# pcs status
Cluster name: mycluster
Last updated: Thu Oct 26 03:49:50 2017      Last change: Wed Oct 25 11:01:51 2017 by root via crm_resource on node1
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node1 (version 1.1.13-10.el7-44eb2dd) - partition with quorum
3 nodes and 6 resources configured

Online: [ node1 node2 node3 ]

Full list of resources:

 fencer_node3   (stonith:fence_xvm):    Started node1
 fencer_node1   (stonith:fence_xvm):    Started node2
 fencer_node2   (stonith:fence_xvm):    Started node3
 Resource Group: myweb
     webip  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started node1
     mywebserver    (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Started node1
 webfs  (ocf::heartbeat:Filesystem):    Started node2

PCSD Status:
  node1: Online
  node3: Online
  node2: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the resources indentation it appears that the resource webfs is not in fact a member of the group myweb. You can verify this using `pcs status groups`.
You can add the webfs resource to the myweb resource group using `pcs resource group add myweb webfs`

PS: This is clearly a web server resource group, so you have to pay attention to the order in which the resources are added to this resource group, the correct order would in fact be :

1. webfs
2. mywebserver
3. webip